# Some guidance needed upon Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

[html page vertical cutoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYb2P.jpg)  [picture of code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lawCi.png)   How do I get wkwebview(objective c) to show all content of loaded html file rather than vertically cutting half of the page off? (xcode 8.2.1)
system 10.11.6
target ios 8.0 and up

and i am not the best of code, so if there is something that i can learn, I will apply it as i go....

This is the viewcontrollerm code for Xcode8.2.1, I am using  as uiwebview and webview did not pickup the local html file as fluently as wkwebview.I have tried alot of different solutions that obviously did not help..and it is simple...all i want to do is load index.html, i have java written within the html as well as css, and some links to an image folder.If someone could help it would be golden, and Many Blessings...

Also in the photo posted above i am using ios simulator for iphone 6, and as you can see the bottom paragraph of text is cut off, and i can only scroll alittle...It won't let me scroll anyfuther than that. I believe it has to do with the auto layout, making the dimensions of height fixed, where it won't scroll the html anyfurther. I could be totally wrong but if anyone else has any suggestions let me  know...

And the other pictures are of the code for the rest of the project.if it be any help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@interface ViewController () <WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *callJavascriptButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *scriptButton;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// WKWebView
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];

// Add addScriptMessageHandler in javascript: 
window.webkit.messageHandlers.MyObserver.postMessage()
[controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"MyObserver"];
configuration.userContentController = controller;



[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

// baseURL needs to be set for local files to load correctly
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSBundle mainBundle].resourceURL];

}

- (IBAction)callJavascriptTapped:(id)sender
{
NSString *script = @"indexJS()";
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(NSString *result, 
NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error:%@", [error 
localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript result:%@", result);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController 
didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message
{

}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified 
WKNavigation *)navigation;


{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}



@end
```

Comment: We will be happy to help but you need to provide more information. What are you currently seeing? What is the code that makes it look that way? Help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, can i email the information to you?

Comment: The code is too long for me to post it, also with error in its posting format, thats the only reason i asked

Comment: No post it here. If someone else can answer before I have time you'll be better off. There are many talented people who contribute here.

Comment: These posts are showing up out of order. How odd.

Comment: i just posted the code

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned, I'll take a look tomorrow if it isn't solved by then.

Comment: any help greatly appreciated regardless many blessings to you upon your journey of life...

Comment: if you can, please take a screen print of your problem. and edit your question.  There's a button to upload a file (your screen print .png file).  vertically cutting a page off means more to you than it does to us.

Comment: okay doing it now

Comment: Excellent. The more specific you can be the faster you'll get assistance.

Comment: You're right...and the system is el capiton and i am uploading the pictures now

Comment: I can only post two pictures, so i did and thank you for your help so far, may you be blessed...

Comment: Use anchors and auto layout to pin the four sides of your webview to the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's Swift Manual (in iBooks) to see how auto layout works.  Something like this called from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear  (you'll need to adjust the top) should work:

Objective-C:

```
- (void) example {
    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview: webView];
    [webView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [webView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [webView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

Swift:

```
func example() {
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it said build failed when i tried to run the simulator, How exactly should i inject this into the code? and everything is greatly appreciated

Comment: possibly is it because the code is objective c? because the error is saying for fun example - unexpected method body  and use of undeclared identifier 'let'

Comment: It is. I'll rewrite it tonight in objective c.

Comment: I think this is a good start, take a look and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: yea I tried it in objective c but it's swift so it's a no go, and i have tried wkwebview in swift and it has not gone well...when i tried objective c i finally got the wkwebview to actually show the index.html..and here i am

Comment: And the time constraint on me is today, i am using a friends apple laptop and have to return it by the end of the day...im not used to writing in swift, and have alittle background in objective c..

Comment: What do you mean it's swift?  There's two examples: the first is objective c and the second is swift.